# How to increase Text Message Size in ActiveMQ WebSocket transport?

Tags: websocket, activemq-classic, stomp, stompjs

I am using stomp.js to connect to ActiveMQ over WebSocket.

```
var url = "ws://localhost:61614/stomp";
var topic = "/topic/STOMPTEST";
var message = $('#message').val();
stompClient = Stomp.client(url);
stompClient.connect('', '', function (args) {
            console.log('connected');
            stompClient.send(topic, {}, message);
        }, onfail);
```

If message size is more than 16KB, it is getting disconnected from AMQ. Getting and warning at ActiveMQ console .. stating

WARN | Text message too large > 16384 chars for SCEP@3f1de914{l(/10.
119.43.206:65157)<>r(/10.119.43.206:61614),d=true,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{WebSocketServletConnectionRFC6455 p=WebSocketParserRFC6455@3012db7c state=DATA buffer= g=WebSocketGeneratorRFC6455@2607c28c
 closed=false buffer=-1}

While reading through ActiveMQ, I found it can be increased like this, in activemq.xml

```
<transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&amp;transport.maxTextMessageSize=999999"/>
```

But getting same problem.
Please help.

Comment: https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/issues/33 has a user who used the "websocket." URI option prefix instead of "transport."; you might give that a shot.